# handling file paths in AppleScript droplet

Tags: applescript, droplet

I created a droplet that is supposed to pass a file (which is being dropped on the droplet) to a website in safari in a file dialog.

I managed most of it... but the file path I get through "theDroppedItems" starts with file:// and it also includes characters like %20 and ~ and more weird characters.

Is there a way to convert this to a "real path" that safari accepts?

Comment: Items dropped on an AppleScript app would be aliases, so you are most likely looking at a URL encoding.  What does the website want?

Comment: the website opens a standard file upload window in which I want to paste the local file "url" which has been dropped on the droplet

Comment: oh and also I want to be able to pass through a file as an argument by using "open with" in finder is that also being handled the same way?

Answer (score 1):

solved:

```
set inx to item 1 of theDroppedItem
set iny to POSIX path of inx
```